# Convert string to day of week (not exact date)

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat, dayofweek

I'm receiving a `String` which is a spelled out day of the week, e.g. Monday. Now I want to get the constant integer representation of that day, which is used in `java.util.Calendar`.

Do I really have to do `if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("Monday")){...}else if(...){...}` on my own? Is there some neat method? If I dig up the `SimpleDateFormat` and mix that with the `Calendar` I produce nearly as many lines as typing the ugly if-else-to-infitity statetment.

Comment: This is screaming `enum`.

Comment: Tip: Rather than pass around these strings for day-of-week, pass around [`java.time.DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) objects pre-defined in that enum.

Answer (score 14):

## java.time

For anyone interested in Java 8 solution, this can be achieved with something similar to this:

```
import static java.util.Locale.forLanguageTag;

import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor;

import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import org.junit.Test;

public class sarasa {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE", forLanguageTag("es"));
        TemporalAccessor accessor = formatter.parse("martes"); // Spanish for Tuesday.
        System.out.println(DayOfWeek.from(accessor));
    }
}
```

Output for this is:

```
TUESDAY
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` it can also parse the day for a specific `Locale`

```
public class Main {

    private static int parseDayOfWeek(String day, Locale locale)
            throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E", locale);
        Date date = dayFormat.parse(day);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        return dayOfWeek;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        int dayOfWeek = parseDayOfWeek("Sunday", Locale.US);
        System.out.println(dayOfWeek);

        dayOfWeek = parseDayOfWeek("Tue", Locale.US);
        System.out.println(dayOfWeek);

        dayOfWeek = parseDayOfWeek("Sonntag", Locale.GERMANY);
        System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
    }

}
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 6):

For non-English day-of-week names, see [Answer by tete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42810015/642706).

## tl;dr

```
 DayOfWeek.valueOf( "Monday".toUppercase() )  // `DayOfWeek` object. Works only for English language.
          .getValue()                         // 1
```

## java.time

If your day-of-week names happen to be the full-length name in English (Monday, Tuesday, etc.), that happens to coincide with the names of the enum objects defined in the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum.

Convert your inputs to all uppercase, and parse to get a constant object for that day-of-week.

```
String input = "Monday" ;
String inputUppercase = input.toUppercase() ;  // MONDAY
DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.valueOf( inputUppercase );  // Object, neither a string nor a number.
```

Now that we have a full-feature object rather than a string, ask for the integer number of that day-of-week where Monday is 1 and Sunday is 7 (standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) definition).

```
int dayOfWeekNumber = dow.getValue() ;
```

### Use `DayOfWeek` objects rather than strings

I urge you to minimize the use of either the name or number of day-of-week. Instead, **use [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) objects** whenever possible.

By the way, you can localize the day-of-week name automatically.

```
String output = DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
```

That localization is one-way only through the `DayOfWeek` class. To go the other direction in languages other than English, see the [Answer by tete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42810015/642706).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

I generally use an enum, though in this case your input has to be in proper case.

```
public enum DayOfWeek {
    Sunday(1),Monday(2),Tuesday(3),Wednesday(4),Thursday(5),Friday(6),Saturday(7);

    private final int value;

    DayOfWeek(int value) {

        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {

        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return value + "";
    }
}
```

Now, you can get the day of the week as follows:

```
String sunday = "Sunday";
System.out.println(DayOfWeek.valueOf(sunday));
```

This would give you following output:

```
1
```

Comment: Such an enum is now built into Java 8 and later, [`java.util.DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html). Runs 1-7 for Monday-Sunday per [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) standard.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
    private static String getDayOfWeek(final Calendar calendar){
    assert calendar != null;
    final String[] days = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
    return days[calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1];
}
```

Although it would probably be a good idea to declare the days of the week so you don't have to keep declaring them each time the method is called.

For the other way around, something like this:

```
    private static int getDayOfWeek(final String day){
    assert day != null;
    final String[] days = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
    for(int i = 0; i < days.length; i++)
        if(days[i].equalsIgnoreCase(day))
            return i+1;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I think I need it the other way around :-) String to int

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a helper method like

```
public static int getDayOfWeekAsInt(String day) {
    if (day == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    switch (day.toLowerCase()) {
        case "monday":
            return Calendar.MONDAY;
        case "tuesday":
            return Calendar.TUESDAY;
        case "wednesday":
            return Calendar.WEDNESDAY;
        case "thursday":
            return Calendar.THURSDAY;
        case "friday":
            return Calendar.FRIDAY;
        case "saturday":
            return Calendar.SATURDAY;
        case "sunday":
            return Calendar.SUNDAY;
        default: 
            return -1;
    }
}
```

Please, note that using Strings with `switch-case` is only supported Java 7 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Why not initialize what you want once?

```
private static final Map<String, Integer> weekDays;
static
{
    weekDays= new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    weekDays.put("Monday", Calendar.MONDAY);
    weekDays.put("Tuesday", Calendar.TUESDAY);
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not declare a Map:

```
Map<String, Integer> daysMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

daysMap.add("monday", 0);
daysMap.add("tuesday", 1);
//etc.
```

Then, when you need to search:

```
int dayId = daysMap.get(day.toLowerCase());
```

This should do what you need. You could even load the data from some file / database, etc.

Comment: I don't believe this compiles.  And if you fix it, it will effectively be the same as Tala's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8 :

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
```

Then simply use: DayOfWeek.[DAY].getValue()

```
System.out.println(DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getValue());
System.out.println(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY);
System.out.println(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY.getValue());
```

For older version check this answer:
[Convert string to day of week (not exact date)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232340/convert-string-to-day-of-week-not-exact-date)

Answer (score 0):

Use the names built into the `DateFormatSymbols` class as follows.  This returns 0 for Sunday, 6 for Saturday, and -2 for any invalid day.  Add your own error handling as you see fit.

```
private static final List dayNames = Arrays.asList(new DateFormatSymbols().getWeekdays());

public int dayNameToInteger(String dayName) {
    return dayNames.indexOf(dayName) - 1;
}
```